# Create href for each "v-for" using basic list rendering

Tags: javascript, html, rendering, vue.js

What is the correct way to add custom `href` to each link in the list?

For example, i want that `link: 'News'` would have `href="http://example.com/news"`.

Is there a possible way to do something like that:

```
{ link: 'News', href: 'http://example.com/news' }
```

And render it like that:

```
<a v-bind:href="{{ a.href }}" v-bind:class="[foot]" v-for="a in news">{{ a.link }}</a>
```

What i have:

**JS**

```
var footer = new Vue({
 el: '.footer',
 data: {
    foot: 'footmenu',
    news: [
       { link: 'News', },
       { link: 'Latest' },
       { link: 'Business news' },
       // etc
    ],
    business: [
       { link: 'Vets' },
       { link: 'Companion animal' },
       { link: 'Equine' },
       // etc
    ],
    // etc
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a v-bind:class="[foot]" v-for="a in news">{{ a.link }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like following:

```
<a v-bind:href="a.href" v-bind:class="[foot]" v-for="a in news">{{ a.link }}</a>
```

as you don't need braces along with `v-bind`. From the [documentation:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind)

> Dynamically bind one or more attributes, or a component prop to an expression.

Comment: Thanks. It is working. I will accept answer in 10min.